# THREE.js ORBITCONTROLLS changing mouseButtons are not working

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hello i`m trying to make something with THREE.js but for some reason my .mouseButtons are not working

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.target.set( 0, 25, 0 );
            controls.mouseButtons = {ORBIT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT, ZOOM: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE, PAN: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT };
            controls.update();
```

i have THREE.js added in there and i checked if THREE.MOUSE is in there if i add that part of code the mousebuttons fully disable

hope someone can help me out

Comment: before people think i did not do anny research i have been googling for the last 3/4 hours and i could not find any solutions for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [this commit](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/9bea0556fe15ecc68651e51bad34dd916b20022b), the `mouseButtons` object has changed its keys. You no longer specify `ORBIT`, `ZOOM` and `PAN` but instead you map mouse buttons to map buttons. What version of THREE.js are you using? Could this be the cause of your issues?

In the current version, your code should (to my understanding) be written as follows:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.target.set( 0, 25, 0 );
    controls.mouseButtons = {LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT, MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE, RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT};
    controls.update();
```

Notice however that these are already the default mappings so if you don't intend to change them, the whole line could be omitted.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Yeah keep an out for changes in THREE.js. I believe the project is still in an experimental state so things change all the time. Tutorials and example code out there expire very quickly :)

Comment: yeah its realy had to find solutions or tutorials to do what i need i`m going to make a question again soon for snapping block togetter i cant for the life of me can find what i need